# ScalaPB not recognized within build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers, scalapb

Following the instructions for scalaPB, I have added the file `project/scalapb.sbt` to my intelli j project. Here is the file itself
addSbtPlugin("com.trueaccord.scalapb" % "sbt-scalapb" % "0.4.20")

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin" % "0.4.20",
  "com.github.os72" % "protoc-jar" % "3.0.0-b2.1"
)
```

I have added the following lines to my `build.sbt`:

```
import com.trueaccord.scalapb.{ScalaPbPlugin => PB}
PB.protobufSettings
PB.runProtoc in PB.protobufConfig := (args =>
  com.github.os72.protocjar.Protoc.runProtoc("-v241" +: args.toArray))
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that when intelli j tries to refresh the sbt build, it has the following message: `illegal start of simple expression import com.trueaccord.scalapb.{ScalapbPlugin => PB}`

Comment: Is this your complete `build.sbt`? Which version of sbt do you use? Can you force a recent one like 0.13.11 by adding `sbt.version=0.13.11` in your project/build.properties?

Comment: @thesamet From sbtVersion it returns me 13.5. Im using Activator which has a version for its sbt launcher is 0.13.8.

Comment: @thesamet I upgraded to `sbt 0.13.11` and it now works properly.